# How to allow to run one job, but do not allow to run another job?

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

Is it possible in Hudson to allow some people to run one job, but do not allow to run another job?
As far as I can see it is possible only to allow to run ALL jobs.

Answer (score 3):

Hudson's [Matrix-based Security](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Standard+Security+Setup) and Project-based Matrix Authorization allow fine-grained authorization control. I haven't set up the Project-based Authorization on my site, but on the System Configuration screen it says you can set up a project-specific ACL on the job configuration page.